# Retrieve cookie and place in form javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, cookies, restore

I want to make it so when the user returns to the page, cookies should be read and the individual form field values are restored using the saved cookie values.  I have a createCookie() and readCookies() function, but I am stuck and do not know how to proceed.  Right now the page saves the cookies, but now I need to restore the form fields to the values in the cookies saved when the page is revisited.

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="registration">
<input name="fname" id="fname">
<input name="lname" id="lname">
<input id="street" name="street" type="text">
<input id="city" name="city" type="text">
<select id="state" name="state"><option value="" selected="selected">Choose</option>
<input id="zip" name="zip" type="text">
<input name="email" id="email">
( <input id="phone1" name="phone1" size="3"> )
  <input id="phone2" name="phone2" size="3"> - 
  <input id="phone3" name="phone3" size="4">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript>

var regForm = document.getElementById("registration");
var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
var street = document.getElementById("street").value;
var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
var state = document.getElementById("state").value;
var zip = document.getElementById("zip").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var phone1 = document.getElementById("phone1").value;
var phone2 = document.getElementById("phone2").value;
var phone3 = document.getElementById("phone3").value;

function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    } 
    else {
        var expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name+"="+value + expires;
    alert("Cookie being created " + document.cookie);
}
function readCookies() {
    var myCookie = document.cookie;
    var newCookie = unescape(myCookie);
    var pairs = newCookie.split("=");
    var name = pairs[0];
    var value = pairs[1];
    alert(newCookie);
}

readCookies();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have the alert(newCookie); so that i know if the read function is working.  I need help figuring out how to send the cookies back to the form fields on page load.

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to do this, like sessionStorage, which was added in HTML5. But the bigger problem is that you have to decide when to save the values. The best solution might be to attach listeners to each input, and save the values when they lose focus (user clicks something else -- indicating s/he is done with this field).

Then add a script that runs on page load to just set each inputs value if it exists in storage. 
`document.getElementById("registration").value = theValueFromStorage;`